# Issue with neethi and WSO2 DStudio client stub

Tags: wso2, apache-axis

I need to connect to a webservice that have a mutual authentication security policy.

So, I create a stub client in WSO2 Developer Studio 3.1.0 inside my maven java project.
My project use maven to manage my dependencies, so I include the needed libraries to make the client work but I found a funny issue.

If I put this neethi dependencies in this order all work fine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.neethi.wso2</groupId>
    <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.wso2v4</version>
</dependency>         
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
    <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

if I change the order I found this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.findAssertionBuilderTarget(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:134)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getAllOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getExactlyOneOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:113)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:99)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:78)
    at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.getPolicy(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:292)
    at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.populateAxisService(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:57)
    at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.<init>(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:96)
    at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.<init>(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:85)
    at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.<init>(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:133)
    at org.test.webservicesTest.recibews_Test.recibews(recibews_Test.java:329)
    at org.test.webservicesTest.recibews_Test.obtienews(recibews_Test.java:120)
    at org.test.webservicesTest.recibews_Test.main(recibews_Test.java:88)
```

My problem is that I need to package this implementation in a jar file so I create a runnable jar file in Eclipse STS but when I run the jar I see this error:
NOTE: If i remove the 3.0.2 neethi dependency, my eclipse project work fine, but the jar not, with the same error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.neethi.Constants.isPolicyElement(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Z
        at org.apache.axis2.util.PolicyUtil.getPolicyChildren(PolicyUtil.java:287)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:157)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:857)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
        at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.<init>(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:99)
        at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.<init>(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:85)
        at org.test.ws.recibews.RecibeWSServiceStub.<init>(RecibeWSServiceStub.java:133)
        at org.test.webservicesTest.recibews_Test.recibews(recibews_Test.java:329)
        at org.test.webservicesTest.recibews_Test.obtienews(recibews_Test.java:120)
        at org.test.webservicesTest.recibews_Test.main(recibews_Test.java:88)
        ... 5 more
```

Any idea about the solution to this problem??

Thanks.

Comment: I think the way you pack the project does not include the neethi jar file.

Comment: I check this idea as soon as i see the problem and both dependencies are inside the jar file and exist in the manifest

Comment: I think the problem must be org.apache.neethi.wso2 2.0.4.wso2v4 depends on the org.apache.neethi 3.0.0 version. But org.apache.neethi.Constants.isPolicyElement() is available from neethi-3.0.1.jar onwards.

Comment: indeed I remove the org.apache.neethi.wso2 2.0.4.wso2v4 and my project in eclipse work but in the package I see another error. I´m really don´t understand how this work just fine in eclipse, without this org.apache.neethi.Constants.isPolicyElement() method and not in my package jar...even if I put just the version 2.0.5 run well in eclipse, without this method but not in the package jar...

Comment: Remove org.apache.neethi dependency and try.